# SQL Replace comma in results without using replace

Tags: sql, sql-server

I feel like this should be simple enough to do, but have not found any solutions that didn't use replace so far. I have the following select statement I am running, and for some of the columns there are commas separating the values. I would like to replace these commas with semicolons, however I only want to do it in the select statement. I don't want it to alter the values in the tables at all. This is not a one off statement either, or I'd just replace all the commas with semicolons and then revert back.

```
SELECT a.Category_Id, a.Category_Name, ISNULL(b.Category_Alias, '') as Category_Alias, 
ISNULL(b.SUPPORT_NAMES, '') as SUPPORT_NAMES
FROM Categories a
    INNER JOIN CategoryInfo b on b.Category_Id=a.Category_Id
```

For the Category_Alias column, the records are actually stored like `CS, Customer Support` and I want that to show up as `CS; Customer Support` just for the select statement.

Comment: Some example would be helpful.

Comment: Out of interest, why not use REPLACE, as it does exactly what you're asking for?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe you may be confused as to what the REPLACE function is doing. You can use REPLACE within your SELECT statement without altering the data in the database:

```
SELECT REPLACE(MyField, ',', ';') AS NewFieldName
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Don't forget the `As` keyword! Can be a little confusing to some without.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't want to replace the value physically in the table, but ok to [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) on select

So you can

```
Select REPLACE(ColumnName,',',';') 
From TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Most SQL servers implement an inline replace function. Most of them are named replace(), and can also be used in a select statement. 
Example from MySQL:

```
SELECT field, REPLACE(field,',',';') FROM my_table;
```

Comment: Check your Syntax on `Replace()` - only 2 parameters?